# Context-free grammar for the following language

Tags: regular-language, context-free-grammar

How is the context-free grammar of the following language:

[image]

This -

[image]

**How does the value of  A terminate without an $A\to\epsilon$ transition?**

Also, **shouldn't the answer be**:

$S \to aA B$

$A\to a A \mid \epsilon $

$B \to b B \mid \epsilon$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar you describe is equivalent to the first one.  The $A\to a$ transition guarantees that $m>0$ in the same way that your $S\to aAB$ transition does.